# Dapper Query vs QueryMultiple performance

Tags: c#, dapper

I am currently querying 8 times using `Query<>` (8 times because I have to convert some columns into JSON and sometimes separately) to generate one complete result set required. However, I was wondering if it is possible to increase the performance by using `QueryMultiple`. I have a hypothesis that `QueryMultiple` can query all those tables at the same time so I don't have to wait for every single query to complete.

I have one other option. It is use `*Async` versions of the methods.

However, I can't implement `QueryMutiple` without significantly changing the code. Should I use `QueryMutiple` or the `*Async` versions of the regular methods? What is the tradeoff between the two alternatives and which one should I be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QueryMultiple` will perform all queries in one batch resulting in only one round trip to the database while executing eight individual queries with `Query<>` will also result in eight round trips.

If you execute all your queries sequentially (without using the `Async` methods), you are wasting *a lot* of time because the database will idle between returning query results and receiving the next query by your application. Using `Async` may improve the performance because your application can send another query to the database while the previous one is being executed. Using `Async` will still result in eight round trips and batches with one single query though, meaning that using `QueryMultiple` yields (in theory) the best performance in the end.

Comment: Another question, does `QueryMultiple` execute all the queries simultaneously?

Comment: `QueryMultiple` doesn't execute queries, it only sends them over the database connection to the DBMS. It does this in one batch (which is what you mean, I guess). How and in which order the queries are executed depends on the DBMS. The DBMS may execute them simultaneaously, but it doesn't have to. It may depend on the kind of queries as well (e.g. if one query locks a table, another one may not be able to be executed in parallel).